# Sequelize: many-to-many relationship with upsert?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a many to many relationship setup in MYSQL using sequelize (finally),
a books table
a categories table
and a join table

I am seeding the data in the db using json. Currently it works great, but the categories get duplicated. so If i have two books with the category sci-fi, sci-fi is added to categories twice.

is there a way to have the categories 'upsert' so that I can maintain a single source of truth for the category names?

```js
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const data = require('./data.json');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('audible', 'root', '', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mysql'
});

sequelize.authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('connection to db successful');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('connection err: ', err);
  });

const Book = sequelize.define('Book', {
  title: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  subtitle: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
  },
  author: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  narrator: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  imageUrl: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
  },
  audioSampleUrl: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
  },
  length: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(10)
  },
  version: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
  }
});

const Category = sequelize.define('Category', {
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    unique: true
  }
});

const Book_Category = sequelize.define('Book_Category', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  book_id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
    primaryKey: false,
    unique: true,
    refrences: {
      model: Book,
      key: 'id',
    },
    onDelete: 'cascade',
    onUpdate: 'cascade',
  },
  category_id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
    primaryKey: false,
    unique: true,
    refrences: {
      model: Category,
      key: 'id',
    },
    onDelete: 'cascade',
    onUpdate: 'cascade',
  }
}, {
  timestamps: false,
  freezeTableName: true
});


Book.belongsToMany(Category, {
  through: Book_Category,
  as: 'categories',
  foreignKey: 'book_id'
});

Category.belongsToMany(Book, {
  through: Book_Category,
  as: 'books',
  foreignKey: 'category_id'
});

sequelize.sync({ force: true })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('table creation succesful');
    return Book.bulkCreate(data, {include: 'categories', upsert: true});
  })
  .then ((result) => {
    console.log('database seeded successfully');
    return sequelize.close();
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('**ERROR: ', err);
    return sequelize.close();
  });
```

and here is the json data

```
[
  {
    "title": "A Promised Land",
    "subtitle": "",
    "author": "Barack Obama",
    "narrator": "Barack Obama",
    "imageUrl": "link.jpg",
    "audioSampleUrl": "link.mp3",
    "length": "29:10",
    "version": "",
    "categories": [
      { "name": "Biographies & Memoirs" },
      { "name": "Politics & Activism" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "My Own Words",
    "subtitle": "",
    "author": "Ruth Bader Ginsburg, Mary Hartnett, Wendy W. Williams",
    "narrator": "Linda Lavin",
    "imageUrl": "link.jpg",
    "audioSampleUrl": "link.mp3",
    "length": "13:16",
    "version": "Unabridged Audiobook",
    "categories": [
      { "name": "Biographies & Memoirs" },
      { "name": "Politics & Activism" }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Please add a part of `data.json` to your post

Comment: You have a type - `refrences` is misspelled twice.

Comment: aha I do. thank you! That doesn't change my issue however. still getting duplicate entries for the category